# How do I get this C++ code to read five integers from the user instead of one?

Tags: c++

I'm taking an elementary programming course where we use C++ and I'm stuck on a couple of assignments. Please excuse my potentially bad terminology going forward. Part of my basic program I'm writting asks "Write down 5 integers: " and then the user gets to pick the integers and a message "You wrote the integers: n1 n2 n3 n4 n5" is returned. There are several of these questions and I'm not allowed to use more then one variable of the same type. The problem is that the user could respond with n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 hello, and hello is supposed to be ignored. How do I accomplish this?

If we for a moment assume that we are only to write down one integer instead of 5, then perhaps something along the lines of the code below would work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int num;
     cout << "Write down an integer: "
          << flush;
     cin >> num;
     cout << "You wrote the integer: "
          << num
          << endl;   
}
```

But how do I do this with five integers. Further, how do I ignore that extra hello? I'm assming that cin.ignore is to be used here somehow.

Comment: Just put that code in a loop that repeats 5 times. Btw you do not have to flush `std::cout` before reading from `std::cin`.

Comment: Read the section in your c++references on loops. This problem seems well suited to a `for` loop.

Comment: "_I'm not allowed to use more then one variable of the same type_" - Then perhaps an array, like `int num[5];` would be allowed? That would fit well with the loop the other guys suggested.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Other guys? I'll have you know, sir, that [*I* am a chihuahua.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog)

Comment: @user4581301 Sorry, I didn't mean to use _guys_ in a gender or species specific way. I learned something by that: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/11817

Comment: Once again I fail to be funny. I'm the best there is at what I do.

Comment: @user4581301 :-D :-D _That_ was funny :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the procedure 5 times, you could just copy-paste it, but that's definitely not a good practice. What's much better is to use a loop/cycle, like `for`.

You'll also need to store all 5 integers into memory. You could use 5 variables (`int n1, n2, n3...`), but again, that's not a very good practice and as you state, that's not allowed in your case. Solution is to use an array, which can hold several values of the same type.

Here is a working example with explaining comments:

```
int nums[5];                 // this array will hold 5 integers
int n;

cout << "Write down 5 integers:" << endl;
for (n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {    // run code in the braces 5 times
    cin >> nums[n];          // store typed integer into nth position of the array
}

cout << "You wrote: ";
for (n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {    // run code in the braces 5 times
    cout << nums[n] << " ";  // print integer at nth position of the array
}
```

---

*Note: One could say that both `nums` and `n` are of the same type, `int`. In that case, you could extend the array `nums` to the size of 6 items and use the last one (to which you can refer as `nums[5]`) as an indexing variable for the loops.*

Comment: Style note: I'd move the definition of `n` into the loops. Prevents accidental leakage of the loop index out into the rest of the code where it could cause problems.

Comment: "_One could say that both nums and n are of the same type_" - One would be wrong.